# What's wrong with my query to send an email via Outlook with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

As an image below is my problem with the `Application`. I've tried to add

`Outlook.Application Application = new Outlook.Application();`

but nothing changes

I added namespace as `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

[image: Pic]

---

[image: Pic2]

---

```
    #region Send Email
    private void SendEmail()
    {
        string subjectEmail = "Meeting has been rescheduled.";
        string bodyEmail = "Meeting is one hour later.";
        Outlook.MAPIFolder sentContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
            this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
            (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        foreach (Outlook.ContactItem contact in sentContacts.Items)
        {
            if (contact.Email1Address.Contains("example.com"))
            {
                this.CreateEmailItem(subjectEmail, contact
                    .Email1Address, bodyEmail);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateEmailItem(string subjectEmail, string toEmail, string bodyEmail)
    {
        Outlook.Application Application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem eMail = (Outlook.MailItem)
            this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        eMail.Subject = subjectEmail;
        eMail.To = toEmail;
        eMail.Body = bodyEmail;
        eMail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
        ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: since `Application` is a word that is used in C# as well as in Microsoft.Applications you will need to fully qualify the name space in regards to where you have `this.Application` so try something like `Outlook.Application` or try to Alias the namespace and use that Alias Name.Application [How to Create a Mial Item OutLook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb644320(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is looking for a class-level field called `Application`, which I assume doesn't exist:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder sentContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

Create an instance of `Application` inside the method (like you said you did) and then remove the keyword `this` from the above code:

```
Outlook.Application Application = new Outlook.Application();

Outlook.MAPIFolder sentContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

If you need access to `Application` outside of that method, then create `Application` at the class level (outside of any methods) and instantiate it inside the constructor (if that's appropriate in your situation).

Comment: That worked well for the first problem. However, the second problem cannot be addressed. Please take a look on the additional image to my thread.

Comment: `Error 2 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?` and I've added `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` before.

Comment: The problem has been addressed by the combined help from you and **DJ KRAZE**. Thank you very much.